# How do I add scrollbars to a LinearLayout in Android?

Tags: android, scrollbar, android-linearlayout

How do I add scrollbars to a view in Android?

I tried by adding `android:scrollbars:"vertical"` to the `LinearLayout` in my layout XML file  but it is not working.

I thought scrollbars were drawn by default in Android but it does not seem that way. It seems we have to draw it ourselves - how do I do this?

Answer (score 56):

You cannot add scrollbars to a `LinearLayout` because it is not a scrollable container.

Only scrollable containers such as `ScrollView`, `HorizontalScrollView`, `ListView`, `GridView`, `ExpandableListView` show scrollbars.

I suggest you place your `LinearLayout` inside a `ScrollView` which will by default show vertical scrollbars if there is enough content to scroll.

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >

        <!-- Your content goes here -->   

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

If you want the vertical scrollbar to always be shown, then add `android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="true"` to your `ScrollView`. Note the height of the `LinearLayout` is set to `wrap_content` - this means the height of the `LinearLayout` can be larger than that of the `ScrollView` if there is enough content - in that case you will be able to scroll your `LinearLayout` up and down.

Comment: Thanks, you helped me too.

Answer (score 12):

You can't add a scrollbar to a widget that way. You can wrap your widget inside a `ScrollView`. Here's a simple example:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/txt"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

If you want to do it in code:

```
ScrollView sv = new ScrollView(this);
//Add your widget as a child of the ScrollView.
sv.addView(wView);
```

Comment: Thanks Rajath.Is working good on my device also.thnk u so much

Comment: you may need to force the size :sv.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));

Comment: Why is the ScrollView `layout_height` set to `wrap_content`, not `fill_parent`?